# Get Gutenberg CSS when fetching post from API

Tags: wordpress, symfony, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to fetch post from my WordPress API in my Symfony Application.

I fetch it with:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/22328"), true);
```

I get post content, featured media etc but the styling is missing so Gutenberg blocks are not rendering well.

How can I fetch Gutenberg blocks CSS from API?

Answer (score 0):

The response to your request to `http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/22328` should contain a blocks section:

```
"blocks": [
    {
      "blockName": "core/paragraph",
      "attrs": {
        "content": "This is a Gutenberg paragraph block."
      }
    },
    {
      "blockName": "core/image",
      "attrs": {
        "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
        "alt": "Example Image"
      }
    },
    // More Gutenberg blocks can follow here
 ]
```

You can render each of this block using the following endpoint: `http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/block-renderer/{$blockName}`

This means you can loop through every object in the `blocks` entry and request the `block-renderer` url, which returns a rendered String for the block.

```
$renderedContent = '';
foreach ($postData['blocks'] as $block) {
    $blockName = $block['blockName'];
    $blockRenderUrl = "http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/block-renderer/{$blockName}";

    // Set up the request headers
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );

    // Set up the request arguments
    $args = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => json_encode($block['attrs']),
    );

    // Make the request to the block-renderer endpoint
    $response = wp_remote_request($blockRenderUrl, $args);

    // Check if the request was successful and get the rendered block content
    if (is_array($response) && !is_wp_error($response)) {
        $renderedBlock = json_decode($response['body'], true);
        if (isset($renderedBlock['rendered'])) {
            $renderedContent .= $renderedBlock['rendered'];
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be send via an Response Object

Comment: There is no "blocks" section in the response of my request. Gutenberg blocks are already nicely rendered in html in "content -> rendered", i don't need to loop over blocks.

There are wordpress classes in the html rendered like "wp-heading" or "wp-block-gallery" but as i don't have gutenberg blocks stylesheet , it is not rendering well, I have to re do all css of Gutenberg in my other website.